# VHDL Assigning Multiple Values to One Signal

Tags: signals, vhdl

```
Process(CLK,Clr,Set)
begin
    if Clr = '1' then Q <= '0';
    elsif Set = '1' then Q <= '1';
    elsif CLK'event and CLK <= '0' then Q <= D;
    end if;
end process;
```

What happens if Clr = Set = '1'?
What is the value of Q?

Comment: This looks like a homework problem. Trace through to see what happens when both are '1'. Think about when signal assignments take effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"if - elsif" is a priority structure.  The first alternative to resolve to TRUE, is executed.  All others are skipped.

> Blockquote What happens if Clr = Set = '1'? What is the value of Q?

Since Clr is first in your code, Q will become '0'.